# Open Source Phone OS

Tags: 16.04, configuration, titlebar

I have no concerns if any government decided to own my phone and review my activity and even track my whereabouts (I am not OK with that, but I have no worries).  That being said, I am concerned about professional experts that are contracted ($ Millions) to co-opt phones using zero-day exploits.

This ability for non-government (criminal) actors to gain access to email, passwords, and other credentials provide the toehold to gain access to banking and other areas.  While I embrace new tech and want to be the last person to put tin foil on my head, I feel that security posture is needed.

Although Android is quasi-open source Linux and the Ubuntu phone really has not taken hold, what are the truly open-source options for smartphones?  Is  the Ubuntu phone truly opensource: why and why not?

Comment: Define “truly open-source”. On most platforms there's only so far you can go with open source software because many hardware subsystems have their proprietary, closed-source on-chip firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most open-source phone OS is Tizen. It is backed-up by the Linux Foundation. Samsung is using Tizen on some of its' low-end phones, but it is with minor to moderate success. Tizen is about the same class as FirefoxOS. Android is one class above that and Ubuntu is (at least) one class above Android.
You should be aware that Ubuntu is the only true-convergent OS. Ubuntu OS can run on virtually ANY device by using an appropriate interface: Unity, Touch, KDE, Xfce, lxde, etc.
Ubuntu IS open-source, because it uses open-sources components. But is also uses some (not so many) closed-source components.